# Not able to get value of option from selectpicker multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a selectpicker multiselect dropdown. When I select multiple values from the dropdown, I want to add equal number of rows to a table which already exists. I was able to get the amount of options selected and add equal number of rows to table but when I try to display those values, I'm getting a problem.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

When I select option 'bed' it displays 'bed' in the table and then if I select 'water', option 'bed' gets added instead. I'm not able to fix this bug. 
Here's javascript/jquery code:

```
    function addc(sel) {

        alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
        count=0;
        var options = document.getElementById("select1").options;

        for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {

            if (options[i].selected) count++;
        }


        var tableRef = 
document.getElementById('items').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length-1 == 
count);

        var str = document.getElementById("select1").value;
        strSplit = str.split(',');




        //  alert(idx);
         qty = Math.random();

           var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();

          newCell.innerHTML="<tr class='item-row'><td class = 'item-
name'><input style='width: 210px;' form ='billsave' class= 'form-
control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'feetype' name= 'feetype' 
value='"+strSplit[0]+"' required> </td></tr>";


          newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td class = 'item-name'><input form 
='billsave'  class= 'form-control input-sm' style='width: 210px;' 
type='text' id = '"+strSplit[1]+"' onblur = 
calc("+strSplit[1]+","+qty+"),totalIt()  name= 'charges' 
value='"+strSplit[1]+"'  required  ></td></tr>";


          newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr class='item-row'><td><input form 
='billsave' class= 'form-control input-sm' style='width: 200px;' 
type='text'  id = '"+qty+"' name= 'price'  required  ></td></tr>";

          newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
          newCell.innerHTML="<tr><td class=''><i class='fa fa-close' 
style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";



    }
```

Here's the JSFiddle:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coder33455/u1m0yvdv/1/)

Comment: fiddle link dont work?

Comment: sorry, its working now.

Comment: It doesnt work like image you specified in question. Did you check the fiddle